# delete the session object in Parse when user uninstalls the app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I noticed that if user uninstall the app without logging out first, then reinstall the app, then login again, a brand new session will be created on parse (together with a new Installation record).
So it will leave zombie records in both Installation table and Session table.
Should I do something to clean up the session table?

Comment: `PFSessions` are local representations of a session. `PFInstallations` are local representation of an installation persisted to the Parse cloud. So yes, once an app is deleted, their local cache is deleted with it, ergo a new record is created upon a new installation. This has been the case for a long time, so that way your not using more API requests for deviceTokens not valid, wasting your API request usage rapidly. This is working as intended

Comment: I was just wondering whether those zombie sessions and installations will hurt query performance in the future.

Comment: No they will not. Once an installation has been deleted the device token is revoked. Query performance won't be altered